# Select team that consists of members that belong to the same, single department

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to make an sql request that turned out surprisingly difficult to me (or maybe this is just the end of the day, sigh).

I have 3 tables:

Team:

| id |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

Team member table:

| id | team_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 9 | 3 |
| 10 | 3 |
| 11 | 3 |
| 12 | 3 |

Team member info table:

| id | team_member_id | department_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 12 |
| 3 | 2 | 43 |
| 5 | 3 | 23 |
| 7 | 4 | 12 |
| 9 | 5 | 12 |
| 11 | 6 | 12 |
| 13 | 7 | 12 |
| 15 | 8 | 12 |
| 17 | 9 | 43 |
| 19 | 10 | 23 |
| 21 | 11 | 14 |
| 23 | 12 | 23 |

These tables are simplified, so don't pay much attention to its structure.

What I need to do is to find `id`s of teams which consists of members that belong to SINGLE `department_id` and this department id should be a parameter.

So in our example I need to find teams, which members belong to department 12.

This is team(id=2) since it consists of members id=5,6,7,8 and all of them belong to department 12.
Team 1 and Team 3 doesn't suit our needs since its members belong to multiple departments: (12, 43, 23) and (43, 23, 14) respectively.

Thanks a lot!

UPD:

I came to solution:

```
Select M.team_id
From Team_Member As M Inner Join Team_Member_Info As I On (M.id=I.team_member_id)
Group by M.team_id
Having count(*) = 1 
       And avg(I.department_id)=12;
```

but the accepted one looks cleaner to me (and moreover it is probably more performant)

Comment: does this https://dbfiddle.uk/UrRJOGfo solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could also be done with other aggregate functions `max` and `min`.

```
Select M.team_id
From Team_Member As M Inner Join Team_Member_Info As I On (M.id=I.team_member_id)
Group by M.team_id
Having Max(I.department_id)=Min(I.department_id)
       And Max(I.department_id)=12;
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dAt7gLyH)

Answer (score 1):

this query selects the teams whose members belong all to department_id = 12 :

```
SELECT tm.team_id
  FROM Team_member_info tmi
 INNER JOIN Team_member tm
    ON tm.id = tmi.team_member_id
 GROUP BY tm.team_id
HAVING bool_and(tmi.department_id = 12)
```

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/t5nzw2DD)